/dev/kvm in docker swarm service
I'd like to run multiple docker-android instances in docker swarm.
But they fail:
ERROR   | x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-linux
CPU acceleration status: /dev/kvm is not found: VT disabled in BIOS or KVM kernel module not loaded

My node supports kvm and running directly on the node with docker compose when adding privileged: true works fine.
But docker swarm doesn't support privileged mode!
They recently added cap_add support in swarm, so I tried to add all available caps, but none of them enables kvm inside the container.
Devices is also not supported in swarm mode!
devices:
      - "/dev/kvm:/dev/kvm"

I know about this workaround for priviledge mode, but I want to make use of the deploy resources limits to auto select nodes based on memory.

One workaround would be to deploy https://github.com/allfro/device-mapping-manager and then just mount /dev/kvm and let the manager fix cgroups automatically
volumes:
  - "/dev/kvm:/dev/kvm"

There's a pull request which implements device support for swarm:
https://github.com/moby/swarmkit/pull/3186
